# Flutter / flutter_webview_plugin => hide/show AppBar + BottomNavigationBar on Scroll down/up

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a WebviewScaffold. It works well, but now I want to hide the BottomNavigationBar and the AppBar on Scroll up. OnScroll down it should show the AppBar and BottomNavigationBar. Like it works in Chrome on iOS.

As I know I cant use a Sliver because 
"Warning: The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs ..."

It would be Nice if somebody could help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get ScrollParams.... But now I have to hide/show the AppBar and the BottomNavigationBar.

```
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
   _onScrollYChanged =
    flutterWebViewPlugin.onScrollYChanged.listen((double x) {
  if (mounted) {
    print(_onScrollYChanged.toString());

    setState(() {
      if (_posY < x) {
        _showBar = false;
        print("DOWN");
      } else {
        _showBar = true;
        print("UP");
      }
      _posY = x;
      print("Scroll in Y Direction: $x");
    });
  }
});

}
```

My Build in my APP looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WebviewScaffold(
    url: "https://www.domain.de",
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarOpacity: _showBar ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      title: const Text('Widget WebView'),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.apps),
        onPressed: () {
          flutterWebViewPlugin.goBack();
        },
      ),

    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () {
              flutterWebViewPlugin.goBack();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    withZoom: true,
    withLocalStorage: true,
    hidden: true,
    headers: _HTMLheaders,
  );
}
}
```

Comment: From where you are getting flutterwebviewplugin